# Error 502 Bad Gateway on Ngrok when i try connect with alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ngrok

when i try connect amazon develper with raspberry pi, using ngrok, only output 502 Bad Gateway.
I tried all, and i saw a lot fórums like this, but anything worked. I'm trying https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx14R0IYYGH3SKT/flask-ask-a-new-python-framework-for-rapid-alexa-skills-kit-development.
Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try using ./ngrok http 127.0.0.1:YOUR_PORT

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH this just ended a 3 hour ngrok related headache!

Comment: XD I spent the same amount of hours of ngrok headache

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your program is running on the Pi. Check localhost:"Your port number" and see if your default page shows up. ngrok simply tunnels whatever is on your localhost onto a web endpoint. Make sure your port number is correct. I know Flask-Ask uses port 5000.